# Empty dictionary in function triggers pandas error

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function which works as it should:

```
def format_df(active_posts, inactive_posts, active_impressions, inactive_impressions):

    for name, data in vars().items():
        df = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
        df.fillna(0)
        df[4] = df[0] / df[2]
        df[5] = ((df[0] - df[1]) / df[1]) * 100
        df = df.drop(1, 1)
        df = df[[0, 5, 2, 4]]
        df[5] = df[5].round()
        df[4] = df[4].round()

        if name == "active_posts" or name == "inactive_posts":
            df.columns = ['Posts', 'MoM Change (%)', 'Editors', 'Posts/Editor']
        if name == "active_impressions" or name == "inactive_impressions":
            df.columns = ['PVs', 'MoM Change (%)', 'Editors', 'PVs/Editor']
```

But when I add an empty dictionary in, which I would like to add data to like this:

```
def format_df(active_posts, inactive_posts, active_impressions, inactive_impressions):

    EMPTY_DICT = {}

    for name, data in vars().items():
        df = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
        df.fillna(0)
        df[4] = df[0] / df[2]
        df[5] = ((df[0] - df[1]) / df[1]) * 100
        df = df.drop(1, 1)
        df = df[[0, 5, 2, 4]]
        df[5] = df[5].round()
        df[4] = df[4].round()

        if name == "active_posts" or name == "inactive_posts":
            df.columns = ['Posts', 'MoM Change (%)', 'Editors', 'Posts/Editor']
        if name == "active_impressions" or name == "inactive_impressions":
            df.columns = ['PVs', 'MoM Change (%)', 'Editors', 'PVs/Editor']
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "monthly_teams_report.py", line 271, in <module>
    main()
  File "monthly_teams_report.py", line 266, in main
    format_df(active_posts, inactive_posts, active_impressions, inactive_impressions)
  File "monthly_teams_report.py", line 235, in format_df
    df[4] = df[0] / df[2]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1797, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1804, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1084, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2851, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1572, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3824)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 686, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12280)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 694, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12231)
KeyError: 0
```

Why would adding that empty dictionary outside of my loop cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used `vars()`, which gives you all local variables.  You added a new local variable called `EMPTY_DICT`, which then goes through your loop like the rest.  It results in an empty DataFrame being created, which then leads to an error when you try to do `df[0]` (because there is no 0th column).

Using `vars` is risky for just this reason.  It would be better to have your function accept a list or dictionary of items to iterate over.  Don't try to use the names of variables as data (as you are doing here with your checks like `if name == "active_posts"`).

Comment: what would you do instead of `if name == "active_posts"`

Comment: @meter: Pass a dictionary like `{'active posts': blah, 'inactive posts': blahblah, ...}` instead of separate variables.  Or pass in some other data structure.  The point is you want the information that "this variable holds active posts" to be stored as part of the *value* of the variable, not the *name*.